# Is it possible to omit the processing instruction from an XML document using Nokogiri::XML::Builder

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Print an XML document without the XML header line at the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218711/print-an-xml-document-without-the-xml-header-line-at-the-top)

I'm trying to create a fragment of XML using the Nokogiri::XML::Builder but I can't find any documentation on how to exclude the processing instruction (`<?xml version=...`)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I can't answer my own question yet buy here is the answer:

`doc.to_xml :save_with => Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::NO_DECLARATION`


If you don't want this huge path in your code, you can also just pass the constant's definition instead:
`Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::NO_DECLARATION` is a constant defined as `2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I can answer:

`doc.to_xml :save_with => Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::NO_DECLARATION`