# Print an XML document without the XML header line at the top

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I am just trying to find out how to to a `to_xml` with a `Nokogiri::XML::Document` or a `Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment`.

Alternatively, I would like to use xPath on a `Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment`. I was unable to ascertain how to do that, however I am successfully parsing a `Nokogiri::XML::Document`.

I am later including a parsed and modified `DocumentFragment` into another piece of XML, but I'm *really* getting bitten on what I thought would be some really simple things.

Like trying to do a `to_xml` on a doc or docfrag, and NOT INCLUDING that xml line at the top. Why so hard?

Comment: Your 'question' is a little rambling. What does XPath on a doc fragment have to do with this question?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The simplest way to get the XML for a `Document` without the leading "PI" ([processing instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_instruction)) is to call `to_s` on the root element instead of the document itself:

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri.XML('<hello world="true" />')

puts doc
#=> <?xml version="1.0"?>
#=> <hello world="true"/>

puts doc.root
#=> <hello world="true"/>
```

The 'correct' way to do it at the document or builder level, though, is to use [`SaveOptions`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node/SaveOptions):

```
formatted_no_decl = Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::FORMAT +
                    Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::NO_DECLARATION

puts doc.to_xml( save_with:formatted_no_decl )
#=> <hello world="true"/>

# Making your code shorter, but horribly confusing for future readers
puts doc.to_xml save_with:3
#=> <hello world="true"/>
```

---

Note that [`DocumentFragment`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/DocumentFragment.html)s do *not* automatically include this PI:

```
frag = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse('<hello world="true" />')
puts frag
#=> <hello world="true"/>
```

If you are seeing a PI in your fragment output, it means it was there when you parsed it.

```
xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?><hello world="true" />'
frag = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(xml)
puts frag
#=> <?xml version="1.0"?><hello world="true"/>
```

If so, and you want to get rid of any PIs, you <strike>can do so</strike> *should* be able to do so with a little XPath:

```
frag.xpath('//processing-instruction()').remove
puts frag
```

…except that [this does not appear to work](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/572) due to [oddness with XPath in DocumentFragments](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/370). To work around these bugs do this instead:

```
# To remove only PIs at the root level of the fragment
frag.xpath('processing-instruction()').remove
puts frag
#=> <hello world="true"/>

# Alternatively, to remove all PIs everywhere, including inside child nodes
frag.xpath('processing-instruction()|.//processing-instruction()').remove
```

---

If you have a [`Builder`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html) object, do either of:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new{ |xml| xml.hello(world:"true") }

puts builder.to_xml
#=> <?xml version="1.0"?>
#=> <hello world="true"/>

puts builder.doc.root.to_xml
#=> <hello world="true"/>

formatted_no_decl = Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::FORMAT +
                    Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::NO_DECLARATION

puts builder.to_xml save_with:formatted_no_decl
#=> <hello world="true"/>
```

Comment: it used to take me to `#attributes-i-<something>` instead of `#attributes`. Looking at the history now, I don't see that reference anymore. If it's my mistake, please disregard/undo it.

Comment: See also [the correct solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215508/is-it-possible-to-omit-the-processing-instruction-from-an-xml-document-using-nok)

Comment: Thank you, @onions; I've added your findings to this answer, and also upvoted your answer and question.

Comment: Using NO_DECLARATION causes the output to lose all formatting, which kinds sucks (newlines and indentation).

Comment: @aaa90210 Thanks for pointing this out. So what you really want is to use `save_with: (Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::NO_DECLARATION + Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::FORMAT)`...or, very ugly, just `save_with:3`.

Comment: @Phrogz I used :indent => 4 and it also worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do this in rails: `skip_instruct: true`

```
 ['array of', 'strings'].to_xml skip_instruct: true, skip_types: true

 => "<strings>\n  <string>array of</string>\n  <string>strings</string>\n</strings>\n"
```