# How can I generate XML with Nokogiri without "<?xml version=..."?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Print an XML document without the XML header line at the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218711/print-an-xml-document-without-the-xml-header-line-at-the-top)

I have a problem with Nokogiri::XML::Builder. I am generating XML wth this code:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do 
    request {
        data '1'
    }
end
```

And the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><request><data>1</data></request>
```

How can I remove:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

from my XML?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Maybe take just the root node of the current Document object being built – [`.doc`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html#attributes) – instead of the whole document?

```
builder.doc.root.to_s
```

Comment: it raise error(Document already has a root node).
But builder.parent.root.to_s doesn't. Thank. You make me thing in right way )

Comment: Should be `builder.doc.root.to_xml` (or `to_s`).

Answer (score 7):

A quick and dirty answer is to tell Nokogiri to reparse the resulting output, then look at the root:

```
require 'nokogiri'

builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do 
  request {
    data '1'
  }
end

puts Nokogiri::XML(builder.to_xml).root.to_xml
```

Which outputs:

```
<request>
  <data>1</data>
</request>
```