# Convert Hash to XML omitting XML header declaration

Tags: ruby, xml, hash

I'd like to convert a standard hash to XML notation.
At the moment I'm doing:

```
hash.to_xml
```

This results in a valid XML, yet this includes the line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`.

Is there a way to convert to XML but without this line (hence the need to XML notation only).

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218711/print-an-xml-document-without-the-xml-header-line-at-the-top

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the `skip_instruct` options to the [`Hash#to_xml`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-to_xml) method:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash'
{:foo => 'bar'}.to_xml
# => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding...

{:foo => 'bar'}.to_xml(:skip_instruct => true)
# => "<hash>\n  <foo>bar...
```